# Yield in foreach or GetEnumerator()?

Tags: c#

Which is preferable in this case:

```
IEnumerator<Cat> EnumerateCats()
{
    var rawCats = GetRawCats();

    foreach(var cat in rawCats)
    {
        var typedCat = new Cat
        {  
            Name = cat.Key;
            Breed = cat.Value;
        };

        yield return typedCat;
    }
}
```

or

```
IEnumerator<Cat> EnumerateCats()
{
    return GetRawCats()
       .Select(cat => new Cat
        {  
            Name = cat.Key;
            Breed = cat.Value;
        })
       .GetEnumerator();
}
```

I prefer last code example. Does it work the same way as the first one?

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure why you would need to return an `IEnumerator<Cat>`.  I would simply change it to return an `IEnumerable<Cat>`, so you can simply write:

```
IEnumerable<Cat> EnumerateCats()
    => GetRawCats()
       .Select(cat => new Cat
        {  
            Name = cat.Key;
            Breed = cat.Value;
        });
```

Comment: It's legasy code. I need to override existing method: virtual IEnumerator<Cat> EnumerateCats().

Comment: If that's your constraint, just pick the approach you like best (I also prefer the second). I really doubt there is any difference between both approaches worth thinking about.

Answer (score 0):

You can see the difference of writing your method with `yield` and without it in this example

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    foreach (int i in List())
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"In List foreach {i}");
    }
    Console.WriteLine("*****");
    foreach (int i in Yield())
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"In Yeild foreach {i}");
    }
}

private static IEnumerable<int> List()
{
    var inputList = new List <int> { 1, 2, 3 };
    List<int> outputlist = new List<int>();
    foreach (var i in inputList)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"In List Method {i}");
        outputlist.Add(i);
    }
        return outputlist.AsEnumerable();
}

private static IEnumerable<int> Yield()
{
    var inputList = new List<int> { 1, 2, 3 };
    foreach (var i in inputList)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"In Yield Method {i}");
        yield return i;
    }
}
```

Here is the output :

```
In List Method 1
In List Method 2
In List Method 3
In List foreach 1
In List foreach 2
In List foreach 3
*****
In Yield Method 1
In Yield foreach 1
In Yield Method 2
In Yield foreach 3
In Yield Method 3
In Yield foreach 3
```

Comment: There is not such difference in OP code. In both cases OP return lazy enumerated collection.

Answer (score -1):

With the use of the yield statement you have less memory usage,
because the call returns each time the yield statement is reached. The other way the hole  collection is build before returning to the caller.